# MacVim startup errors

Tags: macvim

Whenever starting macvim from the terminal the console outputs a series of errors

```
2012-04-22 23:38:16.622 MacVim[27896:60b] speedup org.vim.MacVim
2012-04-22 23:38:16.623 MacVim[27896:60b] ERROR: Unable to find method [_NSFullScreenTransition _startFullScreenTransitionForCGWindow:targetFrame:duration:].
2012-04-22 23:38:16.624 MacVim[27896:60b] ERROR: Unable to find method [_NSFullScreenTransition _startEnterFullScreenTransitionForCGWindow:targetFrame:duration:].
2012-04-22 23:38:16.624 MacVim[27896:60b] ERROR: Unable to find method [_NSFullScreenTransition startExitFullScreenTransitionForCGWindow:targetFrame:duration:].
git: Permission denied
```

Is this problem with macvim or just my configuration?

Comment: Fullscreening changed a bit in Lion. It looks like a fullscreen-related issue; see if you can get a different build of macvim for Lion.